# How can I make this google map dark?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using this type of code for google map location:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:280px;width:auto;">
<div id="gmap_canvas2" style="height:300px;width:auto;"></div>
<style>
    #gmap_canvas2 img {
        max-width:none!important;
        background:none!important
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init_map() {
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 16,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.193444, 28.649466),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas2"), myOptions);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(44.193444, 28.649466)
        });
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: "<b>Club Megalos</b><br/>B-dul Mamaia, nr.155<br/> Constan&#539;a, Rom&acirc;nia"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
</script>
```

And I have this theme but I don't know how to use it, or where to put it.

```
[{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.locality","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"saturation":"-100"},{"lightness":"30"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.neighborhood","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.land_parcel","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"gamma":"0.00"},{"lightness":"74"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":"3"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]}]
```

It's from this website https://snazzymaps.com/style/1261/dark

Comment: On that page is a link to download the full example which shows you the exact code used.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rory McCrossan !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling), `styles` is a property of the [MapOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions) object that is passed in to the `google.maps.Map` constructor.

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q273562y/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function init_map() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.193444, 28.649466),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    styles: [{
      "featureType": "all",
      "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "saturation": 36
      }, {
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 40
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "all",
      "elementType": "labels.text.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "on"
      }, {
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 16
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "all",
      "elementType": "labels.icon",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 20
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 17
      }, {
        "weight": 1.2
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative",
      "elementType": "labels",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative.country",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative.country",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative.country",
      "elementType": "labels.text",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative.province",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative.locality",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }, {
        "saturation": "-100"
      }, {
        "lightness": "30"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }, {
        "gamma": "0.00"
      }, {
        "lightness": "74"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "landscape",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 20
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "lightness": "3"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "all",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "off"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "poi",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 21
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "visibility": "simplified"
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.fill",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 17
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.highway",
      "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 29
      }, {
        "weight": 0.2
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.arterial",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 18
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "road.local",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 16
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "transit",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 19
      }]
    }, {
      "featureType": "water",
      "elementType": "geometry",
      "stylers": [{
        "color": "#000000"
      }, {
        "lightness": 17
      }]
    }]
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap_canvas2"), myOptions);
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(44.193444, 28.649466)
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<b>Club Megalos</b><br/>B-dul Mamaia, nr.155<br/> Constan&#539;a, Rom&acirc;nia"
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  });
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init_map);
```

```css
#gmap_canvas2 img {
  max-width: none!important;
  background: none!important
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:280px;width:auto;">
  <div id="gmap_canvas2" style="height:300px;width:auto;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to implement (along with their library files):

```
<script>styles.push({ id: 1261, name: 'Dark', json: [{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":40}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"all","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"labels","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.country","elementType":"labels.text","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.province","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.locality","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"saturation":"-100"},{"lightness":"30"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.neighborhood","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"administrative.land_parcel","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"},{"gamma":"0.00"},{"lightness":"74"}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"lightness":"3"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"all","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"road","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"visibility":"simplified"}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#000000"},{"lightness":17}]}] });</script>
```